# How to create a virtual host for a QCubed project in xampp on Windows?

Tags: php, xampp, virtualhost, qcubed

in httpd-vhosts.conf I added:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/tef_ticketing/workspace/htdocs"
    ServerName tef_ticketing.dev
    ServerAlias www.tef_ticketing.dev
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/tef_ticketing/workspace/htdocs">
        DirectoryIndex home.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       www.tef_ticketing.dev
```

in configuration.inc.php

```
$url = "tef_ticketing.dev";
define("__DOCROOT_URL__", $url);
```

in home.php

```
<?php
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/qcubed.inc.php');
\QApplication::Redirect('test_page');
```

in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^$ home.php [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^$ ajax.php [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^home$ home.php [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^test_page$ form.php?form=TestForm [L,QSA]
```

In TestForm.class.php

```
<?php
namespace Tef_Ticketing\Presentation\Web\Forms;
use Tef_Ticketing\Presentation\Web\Forms\Form;

class TestForm extends Form {
    protected $btnTest1;
    protected $btnTest2;
    protected $btnTest3;
    protected $lblTest1;

    protected function Form_Create() {
        parent::Form_Create();

        $this->btnTest1 = new \QButton($this);
        $this->btnTest1->Text = 'save1';
        $strJavaScript = "qc.pA('TestForm', 'btnTest2', 'QClickEvent', '', 'QFormWaitIcon');";
        $this->btnTest1->AddAction(new \QClickEvent(), new \QAjaxAction('btnTest1_click'));
        $this->btnTest1->AddAction(new \QClickEvent(), new \QJavaScriptAction($strJavaScript));

        $this->btnTest2 = new \QButton($this, 'btnTest2');
        $this->btnTest2->Text = 'save2';
        $this->btnTest2->AddAction(new \QClickEvent(), new \QAjaxAction('btnTest2_click'));

        $this->btnTest3 = new \QButton($this);
        $this->btnTest3->Text = 'save3';
        $this->btnTest3->AddAction(new \QClickEvent(), new \QAjaxAction('btnTest3_click'));

        $this->lblTest1 = new \QButton($this);
        $this->lblTest1->Text = 'init';
    }

    public function btnTest1_click() {
        sleep(5);
        $this->lblTest1->Text = 'a';
    }

    public function btnTest2_click() {
    }

    public function btnTest3_click() {
        $this->lblTest1->Refresh();
    }

}
```

When I access in browser the following link www.tef_ticketing.dev I am redirected to http://www.tef_ticketing.dev/test_page , and it is ok. But I have an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Tef_Ticketing\Presentation\Web\Forms\Form' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\tef_ticketing\workspace\tef_ticketing-presentation\src\Web\Forms\TestForm.class.php on line 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have a Tef_Ticketing\Presentation\Web\Forms\Form.class.php file with a Form class defined. In your file you are relying on the PSR-4 Autoloader standard: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/. It requires to have a direct relation between the namespace/class names and filesystem folders structure and file names.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`class TestForm extends \Form {`

instead of

`class TestForm extends Form {`